# Chrome DNS lookup time local address

Tags: windows, google-chrome, dns

I'm developing a local site in Windows 7 using WAMP, with a domain of sitename.local. I have sitename.local in my hosts file poiting to 127.0.0.1. I'm getting DNS lookup times of around 6 seconds in chrome. If I immediately reload the page it's instant, but if I wait a minute and reload it I have to wait for a further 6 seconds for the DNS lookup.

My question, why is it having to do a DNS lookup if it's a local address listed in my hosts file? And is there any way I can reduce this time?

A bit of additional information, using the chrome://net-internals I can see that the cache is only ever a minute long, and when this cache expires this is what causes the lengthy lookup time. But should this really affect anything as it shouldn't need to look anything up?

Comment: Having exactly the same issue. 6 sec DNS lookup everytime I'm not refreshing a page for more than a minute. Tried changing settings in httpd.conf and vhosts, but the issue remains.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue may be with the `.local` domain. It has special behavior. I'm not a DNS expert, but had the "pleasure" of debugging a related issue with a friend some time ago. It boiled down to trying to resolve the `.local` domain via multicast in the network. See [a quick explanation here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local).

Try changing to `sitename.com` to force the resolution using the hosts file.